# What is this hose that is leaking yellow/amber fluid?

Tags: ford, leak, ranger, hose

I have a 2001 For Ranger 3.0L V6 engine. This hose started leaking after a 5 minute drive today. Its a fairly slow drip, and it is leaking yellow/amber colored fluid of medium viscosity (slightly more on the watery-side than the oily-side). This hose starts from some some part near the back of the radiator and ends at the back of the engine, looking like it is going into the dash board. The part that I have pointed to with the arrow is a T-joint with another, thinner hose joining to it. The leak is at this T-joint. The thinner hose starts at somewhere near the opposite side of the engine. For the life of me I can't figure out what either of these hoses do. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: engine pic]

Answer (score 4):

Those are heater hoses. They supply hot antifreeze to the heater core so that you have heat in the truck.